# Lookup values from an array using values from another array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my first array where I have the id's of the words I want an array of:

```
$needlearray = (0 => 12421, 1 => 58902, 2 => 912, 3 => 42);
```

Then the second array contains all the words with word data:

```
$haystackarray = (
0 => array('id' => 42, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other"),
1 => array('id' => 12421, 'word' => "good", 'otherdata' => "other"),
2 => array('id' => 58902, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other"),
3 => array('id' => 5222, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other"),
4 => array('id' => 912, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other"),
5 => array('id' => 43290, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other"),
6 => array('id' => 2312, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other")
);
```

I want to output in the fastest way possible, using the `$needlearray` value to look up from `$haystackarray` as the 'id'. e.g. the output I would want using example above is:

```
$result = (
0 => array('id' => 12421, 'word' => "good", 'otherdata' => "other"),
1 => array('id' => 58902, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other"),
2 => array('id' => 912, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other"),
3 => array('id' => 42, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other"),
);
```

Notes:

- Currently I am using a `foreach` loop with array search. It is very slow.
- The original order of `$needlearray` must be maintained.
- The actual data can contain several thousand values in `$needlearray`, and also several thousand arrays in `$haystackarray`.
- Speed is very important as this is part of a large process.

Comment: So, what are you wanting us to do here?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to have the equivalent of an entire database managed in memory.  If speed is an issue, you're doing it wrong.  If this data is not in database to begin with, it should be.

Comment: `$filtered = array_intersect_key($haystackarray, array_intersect(array_column($haystackarray, 'id'), $needlearray));` if you have to do it in PHP

Comment: I was hoping for some kind of php function that would figure out the $result. something like array_intersect where i can match the value of the needle to the 'id' in the haystack.

It is coming from a DB. How do I set this in the query?

Comment: If you're doing it via a database, then a WHERE id IN (...) clause is appropriate

Comment: Just the $haystackarray is coming from the database. the $needlearray is created later

Comment: It would be better if you made one of them an associative array where `id` is the key. Then you wouldn't need inefficient loops, you could match them directly.

Comment: Did you give up or what???

Answer (score 0):

You really want to do this in the database.  You would do something like this:

```
$list  = implode(',', $needlearray);

$query = "SELECT id, word, otherdata FROM table
              WHERE id IN($list)
              ORDER BY FIELD(id, $list)";
```

- Get the rows where `id` is IN the list
- Order by `id` in list order

If you need to do it in PHP then this may or may not be faster than a `foreach()`:

```
$result = array_intersect_key(array_column($haystackarray, null, 'id'),
                              array_flip($needlearray));
```

- Index haystack by `id`
- Flip needle to get the value as index
- Find the intersection (common keys)

The order won't be maintained so then you would need to sort haystack by needle, so the database is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I have queried the database using the ORDER BY FIELD and it is working great :)

Comment: I've just noticed that when I execute the query, it is only receiving unique values. the $query itself is correct. Is there a way to query the database and include duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_intersect function.

```
<?php
    $needlearray = [0 => 12421, 1 => 58902, 2 => 912, 3 => 42];
    $haystackarray = [
    0 => array('id' => 42, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other"),
    1 => array('id' => 12421, 'word' => "good", 'otherdata' => "other"),
    2 => array('id' => 58902, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other"),
    3 => array('id' => 5222, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other"),
    4 => array('id' => 912, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other"),
    5 => array('id' => 43290, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other"),
    6 => array('id' => 2312, 'word' => "hello", 'otherdata' => "other")
];
    $result = array_intersect_key($haystackarray, array_intersect(array_column($haystackarray, 'id'), $needlearray));
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($result);exit();
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://eval.in/584723)

Comment: unfortunately this is not keeping the original $needlearray order.